# Ejecutar perfiles en fila en R

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo un examen de práctica de la asignatura de Metodlogía Cuantitativa: estadística inferencial y no se qué orden escribir en R Studio para calcular los perfiles fila.
Alguien podría resolver mi duda?
Gracias!!!

Comment: Bienvenida Valeria Martinez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo de los datos y eventualmente lo que hubieras intentado o investigado?